# semisimple projective modules over von Neumann non-regular rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am searching the example of semisimple projective modules over von Neumann non-regular ring. I already have an example, it is $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ - $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ with $p$ prime number, this is a semisimple projective module but over von Neumann regular ring. Can someone help me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every [semisimple ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Semisimple_rings) is von Neumann regular, and *every* module over such a ring has the property you seek.

You're welcome.

---